# Change margin from child component from parent component

Tags: react-native, react-redux, styled-components

I'm learning react-native and I'm using styled-components.
In react-native I know its possible to make a component with some style and than the parent can add some extra style like this: 
Parent.js

```
<CardSection style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
```

Child.js

```
<View style={[styles.containerStyle, props.style]} >
```

Then the flexDirection is automatic added to the containerStyle for that element in the parant.
Is there anyway todo something like this in styled-components?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a style to reuse code. But that is rather used for inheritance and you can not extend a button with a div or something like that.

Here is more information:
https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles

What i would do is try normal css inheritance, as that will work in SC aswell. Read up more on this here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance